# Drupal: How to display block/region in views page?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a views page that contains a listing of one of my content type. I used `views-view-list--<name of my view>.tpl` to theme the page. However, the region/blocks that I defined are not displaying. In other pages it works fine, but on the views page it does not. I'm trying to display a `user login block` in my defined region.

Please tell me how to access my `user login block` or my region to display on my views.

Your help is greatly appreciated. I'm using drupal 6 by the way.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think i ran into something similar yesterday. I was trying to print a region, for example

```
<?php print $footer ?>
```

but inside a tpl file that came from views - and for whatever reason, it doesn't output the region from one of the views tpl files.

I used this code:

```
<?php print theme('blocks', footer); // change "footer" to the name of your region ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I am writing this, a safer and maybe recommended way in D7 would be:

```
<?php 
  $region = block_get_blocks_by_region('footer') //first define the block;
  print render($region) // then print the block; 
?>
```

I tried @Garry but I got some errors back from Drupal. [Please see here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22634/i-get-the-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error-when-rendering-re)

Hope this helps someone down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Any page in drupal have page template based on url or content type . So you have to create right page template for your page where views page/block to be displayed. I'm assuming that you are using page template based on url

Comment: I am using the template.php. Is this what you mean? I'm a bit confused on "page template based on url". How can I achieve that? perhaps, that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, except the syntax above needs semi-colons after (); for example print render($region); otherwise thank you for this answer

Answer (score -1):

This is how the snippet will work for Drupal 7 with Bootstrap - HTML tags, considering that the 'billboard' region host an ad:

```
          <aside class="col-xs-0 col-sm-12 role="banner"> 
            <?php
                $region = block_get_blocks_by_region('billboard');
                print render($region);
                ?>
          </aside>
```

Comment: You've posted this content as an answer, but it seems more like you were intending to ask a separate question. If you made a mistake, then please create a new question and delete this answer, else edit your answer.

Comment: Indeed, I posted it as an answer/example of how to use the snippet, but at the same time show the problem with the conditional statement. I'll edit my response and post a new one. Thanks for clarifying this for me.